# Передача данных между серверами по Rest-технологии

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, https

Когда идет работа с клиентом по REST технологии понятно.

```
  @GetMapping("owner")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> getRequestOwner() {

        UserDto dataRequestOwner = requestOwnerService.getDataRequestOwner();

        return ResponseEntity.ok(dataRequestOwner);

    }
```

пришел запрос на указанный адрес сервера от клиента, запрос обработался и был отправлен клиенту.
 Клиент обратился по адресу

```
"api/users/owners"
```

Клиент отправил данные для записи на сервер

```
@PostMapping("users/update/list")
    public List<UserDto> saveUsers(@Valid @RequestBody List<UserDto> list,
                                   BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Input Parameters");
        }

        return userUpdateService.updateUsers(list);
    }
```

Клиент прислал список даннных, они были записаны в базу и затем клиенту были выданы обновленные данные.

А как быть когда клиентом выступает такой же сервер, который то же имеет у себя rest-service, а я как клиент должен вот по такому адресу

```
https://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxx:132213/api/....
```

Получить данные или отправить ему данные

Пожалуйста подскажите пример или статью в сети, где можно описана такая работа между 2-мя серверами.

Кроме того 2-й сервер также запрашивает у меня данные и он выступает как клиент, как сделать заглушку, которая имитировала бы этот второй сервер, чтобы протестировать все это.

Я использую Spring boot.

Comment: Для того, чтобы делать запросы из Java кода, нужен HTTP клиент. Есть куча готовых библиотек  с шикарным функционалом, например, Apache  HTTP client. Можно даже написать свою, стандартная поставка JDK позволяет делать HTTP запросы. 
А вообще, если идет общение между двумя серверами, которые вы контролируете, разумнее использовать какие-нибудь месседж брокеры, напирмер RabbitMQ

Comment: Спасибо. Но может вы знаете в сети пример, где это можно увидеть и попробавть сделать это. Если у вас есть опыт работы в таких задачах скажите с чего начать ?

Comment: Просто гуглите что-то вроде "java make request to rest api" и вам вываливается куча статей и туториалов. Я бы и сам просто открыл бы первую ссылку по этому запросу и начал бы повторять.
Насчёт имитации запросов к вашему серверу - у спринга есть готовое решение. Ищите по ключу "Spring MockMvc".

Comment: @skyho https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template